# Is it possible to install applications in docker container permanently?

Tags: linux, debian, docker

I am using docker but every time i run it, i should install some important applications for my work and that needs some effort to edit sources.list with cat then installing sudo and nano then something else every single time i run docker.

**Is There any way to Save the docker container and re-login into it later?**

I am running ubuntu 16 with docker inside debian 10.

Comment: I'm no docker expert but what you are explaining sounds like the exact purpose of docker.  Are you creating your own dockerfile or using some general purpose one?

Comment: Hi, i am just using general purpose docker file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### With a `Dockerfile`

This is the "normal" way. Basically you create a file (usually named `Dockerfile`) that contains:

```
# The image we will start with:
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install packages, by running a command
RUN apt update && apt install package1 package2

# You can also copy you own script/config files
COPY startup.sh /startup.sh
```

Then you "compile" your image (assuming the directory with the Dockerfile and the script is the current directory):

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

Then your use your image:

```
docker run my_image
```

Complete syntax of Dockerfiles is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

The benefits of this method:

- The Dockerfile is your "recipe" to a working container, no need to make side notes, etc... This how you get a documented and maintainable container.
- You can easily upgrade to a new version of the base image
- You can share the image or transfer it to another machine by just transferring the docker files and the few files that you copy to the container.

### With `docker commit`

You can also create an image from the current container contents:

```
docker commit <containerId> <imageName>
```

The problem is that if the image works, you don't really know what is inside, and it's not easy to transfer (it's a rather big file)

### Notes:

- Until you change the USER, you are root in the container, so you normally don't need `sudo`
- You shouldn't need `nano` either, edit the files outside the container and copy them with the Dockerfile. A container is a throw-away thing...
- Using your own image,the container starts a lot faster, even if there is no network, since you don't need to reinstall things.
- A container is a throw-away item, it's hard to backup or transfer.

Comment: I think that i found the hack. I removed `--rm` from the makefile in my docker folder. I write `docker ps` in my user shell terminal. So now i can see the running container id. Then when i want to exit from docker i use `docker stop <container-id>` and when i want to re-run it i write `docker start -ai  <container-id>` 
If that is Okay please comment to confirm the hack. Thanks. Best Regards.

Comment: Yes, it works but don't. This will cause problems later. You shouldn't care about the container, only about the image. The image is the equivalent of a binary executable, when the container is more like the executing RAM image. Do you take memory dumps to rerun processes?